# AngularJS HTTP Get JSON won't display

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS, been puzzling over this problem all evening.  Trying to load JSON data from a random generator and display it in the view with a service.  {{ main.title }} works but ng-repeat="user in main.users" and {{ user.name }} displays nothing.  Where have I gone wrong?

Index.html

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="users.serv.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">
<div class = "container">
    <h1>{{ main.title }}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="user in main.users">
        <h2>{{ user.name }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

main.ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainController', ['users', function(users) {
    var vm = this;
    users.get(function(data) {
        vm.users = data;
    });
    vm.title = 'Hello World';
}]);
```

users.serv.js

```
angular.module('app').factory('users', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function (callback) {
            $http.get('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bJHFVOzrzC?indent=2').success(function(data) {
                return data;
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I think you need to call your method users.get() method, so that vm.users is initialised and has the required value

Comment: `.success(callback)` should sort it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the callback once the ajax request is over

```
angular.module('app').factory('users', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function (callback) {
            $http.get('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bJHFVOzrzC?indent=2').success(function (data) {
                callback(data);
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zzxtgxkf/)

Comment: I like to pretend that they never added those `success` and `error` callbacks to the `$http` promise

Comment: That did it.  Still trying to wrap my head around this whole callback thing.

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer by Arun, 
Yet another way I prefer is, return http method from factory,then success or error or promise to use in controller as below.

main.ctrl.js

```
 angular.module('app').controller('MainController', ['users', function(users) {
        var vm = this;

        users.get().success(function (data) {       
        vm.users = data;   
       });

    vm.title = 'Hello World';
}]);
```

users.serv.js

```
angular.module('app').factory('users', ['$http', function($http) {
     return {
    get: function (callback) {
        return $http.get('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bJHFVOzrzC?indent=2');          
    }
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get back control over the data returned in ajax response. Either pass your own callback function to be invoked later on once data is received or do whatever you want in the success callback once you return the $http.get(...); everytime you go for an ajax call.